# React Hool re-render loop test Condition on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, frontend

I want to update and re-render for loop test condition on hook state update. After I update state hook the state is rerendered but I want to the loop to be rerendered too. I make a form. The length of the form depends on what number I enter on input.

Here is what I tried:

```
const [formLength, setFormLength] = useState(0);

let eachForm = () => {
  for (let x = 0; x < formLength; x++) {
    return <div>{x+1} inpute</div>;
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  eachForm();
}, [formLength]);

{formLength <= 0 ? (<>Zeroo</>) : (<><eachForm /></>)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `useEffect` hook here, it's not doing anything for you. You can render directly the JSX from the `formLength` state. `eachForm` also isn't a valid React component, so it can't be used like `<eachForm />`. The `for-loop` will also return during the first iteration and not return an array of `div` elements like I suspect you are expecting.

Example:

```
const [formLength, setFormLength] = useState(10);

return (
  <>
    {formLength
      ? Array.from({ length: formLength }).map((_, i) => (
          <div key={i}>{i+1} input</div>
        ))
      : <>Zero</>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the state changes your component is rerendered so there is no need for useEffect. Try something like this:

```js
const [formFields, setFormFields] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <input type='button' onClick={()=>
      setFormFields([...formFields,<p key={formFields.length}>{formFields.length}</p>])} 
      value="+"/>
      <form>
      {formFields}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i mean is i have a number input and as i update this number input it rerenders the loop and gives me a form with length of that input's value